# Adding static data to report builder to use in report

Tags: reporting-services, dataset, reportbuilder3.0, reportbuilder

I am using report builder 3.0 to create reports in a vendor's environment where I only have access to their data sources.  We have static data that we need to use in conjunction with the datasets we are creating from their models and I am trying to figure out how to add our data to a report to use for looking up values.

For Example:

The data set has AccountNo, OrderNo, ItemNo, Quantity, etc.
I need to be able to show some attributes about the ItemNo, like ItemName, ItemCost, ItemValue, etc.

I would like to have a dataset I can lookup against to get these values, but the only way I can get this to work is to create a report code function with hundreds of thousands of IF statements:  IF ItemNo = "12345" Then ItemName = "XYZ Product"

This is slow and cumbersome to say the least.  If the data sources were under my control, I could simply add a table in SQL, but I cannot in this environment.  I have even tried linking to external datasource and that is not allowed by the environment.  I am looking into creating some kind of XML data or trying to add data directly to the RDL, but I am running out of options.

Does anyone know of a any way to add a set of data or create an embedded dataset that contains static values.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance,
Eric.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a shared dataset that uses a table variable. So just create a new shared dataset and use a query like

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(ItemNo int, ItemName varchar(100))
INSERT INTO @t VALUES
    (12345, 'XYZ Product'),
    (23456, 'ABC Product')
SELECT * FROM @t
```

You could use this in each report and do a lookup to it to get the data you require.

Hopefully you have enough access to create a **shared** dataset, if not you would have to copy this to each report but it will be faster than thousands of IIFs

Comment: Thank you for the response.  Unfortunately, I cannot create a dataset using any other than the data source provided.  When creating a dataset, in dataset properties, my only options are to select a data source (existing), and enter Query in text and that looks like it has to be XML, which is not my strong suit.  I can also use query designer for the data set, but that requires me to select a pre-defined perspective.

Comment: Ah , the phrase "perspective" makes me think that you are using SSAS/MDX as the datasource. If that's true you may want to edit the tags on your question as the approach will be different.

Comment: Why a table variable? Wouldn’t a select/union all work in this case?

Comment: You could use unioned selects that but that would be much slower. In any case this will not work as the OP has pointed out other limitations.

Comment: Not sure what the actual source is.  I know that I cannot use SQL statements are this would have been a done deal.  For now the code function with IF statements is working, but blazingly slow.

Answer (score 0):

You could code this in VBA in the custom code section of the report. And/or make this a custom DLL which can source the data from wherever you want. The lookup code would be contained in the custom DLL in that case (pass in an input and the code returns the lookup).

Comment: I am not able to create any thing more than add code to the individual reports.  I have no way to publish anything to the report server other than the RDL files and no way to add any additional data sources than what exists.  I have tried using external data sources, like SQL and share point and the report fails to publish on validation.  I am pretty sure the vendor will not allow external server linking.

Comment: I would pursue the custom VBA code route then. It is something you can add to each RDL without any other permissions or access required. If you need an example I can provide one.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a Data Source of Type XML
2. Create a Data Set and set the Data Source Created at step 1
3. Set Query Type to Text
4. Add some XML there is an example below

You should now see 3 columns in your output, I know its late but I was searching for this myself and hopefully will help someone else

```html
<Query>
     <XmlData>
      <?xml version="1.0"?>
      <Months>
       <Month MonthValue="1">
        <Name="January" />
        <ShortName="Jan" />
       </Month>
       <Month MonthValue="2">
        <Name="February" />
        <ShortName="Feb" />
       </Month>
       <Month MonthValue="3">
        <Name="March" />
        <ShortName="Mar" />
       </Month>
       <Month MonthValue="4">
        <Name="April" />
        <ShortName="Apr" />
       </Month>
       <Month MonthValue="5">
        <Name="May" />
        <ShortName="May" />
       </Month>
       <Month MonthValue="6">
        <Name="June" />
        <ShortName="Jun" />
       </Month>
       <Month MonthValue="7">
        <Name="July" />
        <ShortName="Jul" />
       </Month>
       <Month MonthValue="8">
        <Name="August" />
        <ShortName="Aug" />
       </Month>
       <Month MonthValue="9">
        <Name="September" />
        <ShortName="Sep" />
       </Month>
       <Month MonthValue="10">
        <Name="October" />
        <ShortName="Oct" />
       </Month>
       <Month MonthValue="11">
        <Name="November" />
        <ShortName="Nov" />
       </Month>
       <Month MonthValue="12">
        <Name="December" />
        <ShortName="Dec" />
       </Month>
      </Months>
     </XmlData>
       </Query>
```